# What is forEach and spliterator in Iterable interface, and how to implement with linked list

Tags: java, list, for-loop, linked-list, iterator

I have a data structure that is essentially a linked list, meaning it has nodes containing data that point to the next nodes.

I have looked into facilitating iteration with a for loop on this class and I found that one must implement the Iterable interface. However, I am confused on how to implement forEach() and spliterator(), and what each method does.

Comment: The [`Spliterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) documentation is pretty deep, what specific part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Apparently, it is not necessary for a simple "for" loop, but I would still like to know what it does. If you could provide a brief overview that's hopefully shorter and clearer than the API doc, that would be great.

Comment: Do you know about Java 8 [`streams`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to implement `spliterator()` and `forEach()` methods. Those methods were introduced in Java 8 and they have a default implementation.

As to what they do :

`spliterator()` creates a [Spliterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) over the elements described by this `Iterable`. A `Spliterator` is used for  traversing and partitioning elements of a source (which can be, for example, a Collection). It is used in Java 8 to create parallel [Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)s of objects, which would allow you to perform operations on the items of your `Iterable` in parallel.

`forEach(Consumer action)` performs an action (by calling the `accept` method of the [Consumer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) which is passed to it) on all the elements of the `Iterable`.

Its default implementation behaves like :

```
 for (T t : this)
     action.accept(t);
```

You just have to implement the `iterator()` method, which returns an `Iterator`.

Of course you can read all of this in the [JavaDoc of Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).

Comment: So all I must do is have a method that returns an iterator?

Comment: Although [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#spliterator--) do say (of `spliterator`) *"The default implementation should usually be overridden."* And this answer doesn't shed any light on *"what each method does."* *(Even with the edit, which just begs the question.)*

Comment: A linked list probably won't be able to get a better implementation of `spliterator()` than the default, so you should just go with that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'd say you should consider overriding it only if you are going to use your `Iterable` to create parallel Streams.

Comment: I still don't think this really clarifies anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can implement spliterator:

```
@Override
public Spliterator<A> spliterator() {
    return Spliterators.spliterator(iterator(), size(), Spliterator.ORDERED);
}
```